# Filter data frame from values in different columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new in Pandas and hope that somebody at least can point me in the right direction.

Here comes the actual question:

df:

```
           time               Area      lon        lat      mode         ID
    1993-08-01 00:34:28          A  45.627800  34.733400     false       3183
    1993-08-01 00:34:28          A  45.699600  34.639300     false       3183
    1993-08-01 00:34:28          A  45.603800  34.730600     false       3183
    1992-03-21 01:13:18          A  45.686400  34.548100      false      3184
    1992-03-21 01:13:18          A  45.702400  34.554300     false       3184
    1992-03-21 01:13:18          B  45.304784  34.626540      NaN        3184
    1992-03-21 16:13:20          A  45.633800  34.709700     false       3185
    1992-03-21 16:13:20          A  45.643400  34.709000     true        3185
    1992-03-21 16:13:20          A  45.634600  34.959500     true        3185
```

I want to filter out all instances of **’ID’** that just has data from one **’Area’** (*either A or B*). The **’ID’** s I want must therefore have at least one instance of **’A’** *AND* **’B’** to be stored in a new data frame.

From df presented above only the entires presented below fits the constrain:

```
    1992-03-21 01:13:18          A  45.686400  34.548100      false      3184
    1992-03-21 01:13:18          A  45.702400  34.554300     false       3184
    1992-03-21 01:13:18          B  45.304784  34.626540      NaN        3184
```

Right now I’m about to try to do a regular for loop with if statements and a list to temporary store **’Area’** attributes for each **’ID’**. This feels like a very bad approach and there must be some idiomatic pandas way of doing this.

Comment: Why in output is missing `1992-03-21 01:13:18          A  45.686400  34.548100      false      3184` ?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean? The last two rows is the ones desired, as they is the only entries that shares a unique 'ID' and includes both Area A and B

Comment: Hmm, but area `A` have 2 rows with `ID=3184` and `B` only one. So why in output is only one row from category `A` and not both as in my answer below?

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I have now added the missing output value. I did a stupid mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for removing all values which are not in all groups:

```
print (df.pivot_table(index='Area', columns='ID', values='lat').dropna(axis=1))
ID        3184
Area          
A     34.55120
B     34.62654

vals = df.pivot_table(index='Area', columns='ID', values='lat').dropna(axis=1).columns
print (vals)
Int64Index([3184], dtype='int64', name='ID')
```

Last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print (df[df.ID.isin(vals)])
                  time Area        lon       lat   mode    ID
3  1992-03-21 01:13:18    A  45.686400  34.54810  False  3184
4  1992-03-21 01:13:18    A  45.702400  34.55430  False  3184
5  1992-03-21 01:13:18    B  45.304784  34.62654    NaN  3184
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfect and fast with the full dataset that has over 2 million rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the following :

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]:
  area    id
0    A  3183
1    A  3183
2    A  3184
3    B  3184
4    A  3185
5    A  3185

In [25]: df[df.groupby('id')['area'].transform('nunique') > 1]
Out[25]:
  area    id
2    A  3184
3    B  3184
```

I reduced my example to the only 2 relevant columns (id and area), but this would work without problem with your full DataFrame.

I basically count the number of different areas for every ID, and filter out those with only one area.

Comment: I tried your approach but it did not work for me. Perhaps I did something wrong. Thank you for the help anyway!